# RecyclerView and get ItemId

Tags: android, adapter

I am implementing a swipe to delete with a `RecyclerView` and an `ItemTouchHelper`. Within my `onSwiped` function, I call my service to delete the element with an API request, but for that I need the adapter to give me the id of the element.
I overrided the `getItemId()` function of my Adapter

```java
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return dataSet.get(position).getId();
}
```

However when I am using it in my `onSwiped` function

```java
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
     AddBaseService addBaseService = AddBaseService.sharedInstance();
     long baseId = viewHolder.getItemId(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
     addBaseService.deleteBase(String.valueOf(baseId));
```

I got an error at the `getAdapterPosition` line saying

```
getItemId() in ViewHolder cannot be applied to (int)
```

although `getAdapterPosition` is supposed to return an int :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Here are two links that might help you solve your issue :

- [What is the intent of the methods getItem and getItemId in the Android class BaseAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas)
- [how to get ID of the items in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919116/how-to-get-id-of-the-items-in-recyclerview)

---

OP used : `adapter.getItemId(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` instead of `viewHolder.getItemId()` to solve his problem.

Comment: My problem is not about how to set in an adapter to swipe and delete. I know how to do that and it works. The only problem that I have is about getting the id of the item. For some reasons it seems that it doesn't call the function. It always returns -1

Comment: In that case there is a few subject on SO that might help you, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711592/what-is-the-intent-of-the-methods-getitem-and-getitemid-in-the-android-class-bas and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919116/how-to-get-id-of-the-items-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

i think viewHolder.getItemId() expects long not int

Comment: I tried with a long and I got the same message `getItemId() in ViewHolder cannot be applied to (long)`

Comment: hey , i think you meant viewHolder.setItemId() :/ because viewHolder.getItemId does't expect anything actually :D

Comment: I tried that way first, but for some reasons, it always returns `-1` and when I put a breakpoint in my function getItemId() it seems that it is never called :/

Comment: Maybe you pass the id of the view after you delete it so it never exists , i didn't implement swip-delete before but if you want a way to find views use tags better